# Cell run to completion but kernel is still running

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook does some data extractions. After executed the cell (no * with the cell) and get the extraction results, the kernel is still showing running (and CPU shows ipykernel 100%)

What could cause this happen and how to find out what process causes 100% usage on the ipykernel while no cell is running?

Answer (score 0):

These normally caused by some extensions. Try to check if you have any extension for variable monitor/watch, then disable it.

Alternatively, you can try jupyter lab which has optimized many ways jupyter book issues with extensions.